# Hiding AVPlayerController full screen button

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am loading my AVPlayerController on a specified UIView. Is there a way to hide only the fullscreen button shown on the AVPlayerController?

Comment: you can't hide the particular full screen button, if you want to hide you need to hide entire controls,ios

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is hide all the controls using:

```
YourAVPlayerViewControllerName.showsPlaybackControls = false
```

and then create your own custom controls for the player

EDIT:

Also as mentioned in the comments, **you cannot remove only one button**, if you need the excat the same then you need to customise your view based on your requirment

Comment: but question iis related to hide the particuar full screen button

Comment: sorry you are right and I didn't notice your comment, I agree with you that there is no option to hide a specific one, I'm just giving him another way to handle that

Comment: your answer is fine, but you need to mention your also

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cant, but you can create a customized player using `AVPlayerLayer` then you can do almost anything you want in it but you need to handle everything manually, slider and playback Controls and so.

there are already lots of tutorials on how to achieve that like [this one](http://binarymosaic.com/custom-video-player-for-ios-with-avfoundation/)